# calculate depth from two images with epipolar geometry?

Tags: python, opencv, math, image-processing

lets assume that I have two images (img1 and im2) and only one camera which is not fixed. Is it possible to calculate the depth of some points in the image?

I thought I can do this:

- detect surf feature points
- match the detected points
- calculate fundamental or essential matrix
- calculate Z with Epipolar geometry

Can I do this, I mean is this the right way?
Or will this not work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of these calculations are up to scale. So, you won't get an absolute depth without some kind of reference.

Comment: Hi Nico, 
thx for your answer. what do you mean exactly?
@NicoSchertler

Comment: The same images could have been taken with the scene scaled by an arbitrary factor and the cameras moving closer or farther by that same factor. Hence, you need some kind of reference length.